# Problems with accessing form elements from the DOM in Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, dom

Consider the following example:

```
<form action="process.php" id="myForm">
 ..... 
 ....... all my form elements
</form>
```

I first accessed my form elements this way:

```
function verifyForm() {
    var frm_elements = myForm.elements;
    //do something here
}
```

The above code worked well with the latest versions of Chrome and Internet explorer. However it always failed with Firefox. FF complained about the error : "Could not find the id myForm"

To get this working I replaced myForm.elements with document.getElementById('myForm').elements. It worked fine all the three browsers I tested.

I am just curious to know why did it fail on FF? Did I do anything wrong ?

Comment: Use `.getElementById()` to get the reference of DOM elements. Browsers will create global variables based on DOM elements with `name` and / or `id` properties but you shouldn't rely on that...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

modify this

```
<form action="process.php" id="myForm">
```

to this

```
<form action="process.php" name="myForm">
```

Because the DOM forms collection works off of name, therefore to access using the form name you need to add the name attribute to the tag. Which will allow the following statements to work.

```
document.forms["myform"]
document.forms.myform
document.myform
```

Here is some reference http://www.quirksmode.org/js/forms.html

Comment: +1 This is the only way I could reproduce the problem.  If you pass by `id` things can work out.  But, if you try to access with the literal name it breaks.  http://jsfiddle.net/smacky311/CWFCe/5/

Comment: @JohnHartsock Thanks for such a nice explanation. I understood something new:)

Comment: Actually, you're better off setting both the `id` and `name` attributes to the same value since they reside in the namespace. Note: this would only be applicable in cases where the element can have a `name` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently Chrome and IE bind forms to `document`. This is not standard AFAIK.

```
> foo = 1
> window.foo
1
```

`getElementById` is the right way to go. Although `document.forms.myForm` also works for me.